# Photoswipe Custom Hashtag Immediately Closes Slideshow

Tags: jquery-mobile, hashtag, photoswipe

Testing on the desktop with JQM doesn't produce this issue, so it's difficult to pinpoint.

**Backstory:** I have created server side code (php) to accept a query string and open a gallery straight to a picture. But if a user wants to share a link while surfing a gallery on a mobile device, and in particular a certain photo; most Mobile Browsers share the core link and not the actual photo. It's easy in the events when swiping to create a URL hashtag modifier for the URL with the photo id ( For example #photoID=987), but only if the gallery is originally started with no hashtags. It's then easy to share with a Phone's Native methods.

```js
(function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //More Code is here but not needed fro this question

        $(photoSwipeInstance).bind(PhotoSwipe.EventTypes.onDisplayImage, function(e){
            var pid = codeThatGetsPhotoIDFromDisplayedIMGURL();
            window.location.hash = '&pid='+pid[0];

        });
        if(getUrlVars()["pid"]!=null || getUrlVars()["pid"]!=undefined)
        {
            console.log(getUrlVars()["pid"]);
            var photopid= getPhoto(getUrlVars()["pid"]);
            photoSwipeInstance.show(photopid);
        }
    });//End Documentstrong text
}(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

**Issue:** If a gallery is loaded with a hashtag the gallery will pop up the proper image but then immediately closes the slide show. And every photo past this point performs in the same manner, slideshow opens then closes.

I have turned off all AJAX, and hashtag anchor functions JQM utilizes. This hashtag url functions works as intended when using a Desktop browser but not when using any Mobile browser.

Has someone else tried this functionality?

I probably made this much more confusing then it is in my description.

**Answer:**  JQM's hashtag handlers did not need to be turned off instead.  Photoswipe needed this handler added to the options: `backButtonHideEnabled: false`

Answer (score 0):

JQM's hashtag handlers did not need to be turned off instead. Photoswipe needed this handler added to the options: backButtonHideEnabled: false